# Pycharm Python Console regression output not aligned

Tags: python, pycharm, statsmodels, summary, linearmodels

I am relatively new to Python and Pycharm, so I don't know if it is a silly question.
Suddenly I got a strange problem: the summary output from any kind of regression in python console is not correctly aligned but, if I run the script from terminal, it is perfectly aligned. Some days ago it worked well but now I have this problem with *linearmodels* and *statsmodels*. If you could help me, I'd be very happy, because it's not easy to read it.

This is an example of code that generates the problem.

```
import statsmodels.api as sts
mod = sts.tsa.AutoReg(rt, 1)
res = mod.fit()
print(res.summary())
```

Following, the screenshots.

[Python console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lhd3G.png)
[Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gHqj.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the console is not using a monospace font. Select a monospace font for it, like Courier.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with non-monospaced fonts: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-172886. Please vote for it to get the updates regarding the status changes.

Once you change font to Courier New or other monospaced font, it is necessary to close all Terminal tabs before opening a new session to see the change effect.